# What is the meaning of the "classical-esque term"?

Tags: meaning

So what does the phrase, "classical-esque" really mean? Is it like a style that was used in classical ages or what? Is it something related to the Latin language? What exactly does "classical-esque" mean?

Comment: Do you have an example sentence where you have seen this adjective used? Without context, it's impossible to know in what sense _classical_ is intended. The suffix _-esque_ means something like 'imitating the style of'. My guess is that it means something like 'imitating Roman architecture'.

Comment: It likely depends on what is meant by *classic* in the particular context. Then *classical-esque* is not really classic, but resembling it.

Comment: Like _-ish_, this is a "libfix" -- an affix that's escaped and now attaches to other words. These go outside whatever morphology there is, and indicate some kind of vague approximation. Probly the easiest translation of _X-esque_ is "something that I might call 'X' ". Since it's slang it's always changing.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it in a comment of another question

Comment: Don't you think what 'classical-esque' means might depend on what Comment you saw to what other Question? May we have a citation?